# Residue Calculus - Showing that the quotient of polynomials have integral $0$ in a simple closed contour in a special case.

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, residue-calculus

I'm having difficulty understanding the solution to the following problem.

In the solution below, I can't understand why since $b_m\neq 0$, the quotient of these polynomials is represented by a series of the form $d_0+d_1 z+d_2 z^2 +\cdots$. In fact, since the degree of the denominator is greater, shouldn't the quotient include negative powers of $z$? I would greatly appreciate if anyone could explain this to me.

Problem:

[image]

Solution:

[image]

Comment: For $z$ sufficiently near zero, the denominator approaches $b_m \neq 0$, while the numerator is asymptotic to $a_n z^{m-n-2}$.  By assumption, $m-n-2\ge 0$, so the quotient is asymptotic to $(a_n / b_m) z^{m-n-2}$ as $z\rightarrow 0$; i.e., the residue at $z=0$ is $0$.

Comment: The solution proves that the residue is $0$ at $z=0$, by showing that the coefficient to the first negative power of the Laurent series of that function is $0$.Can you explain why the quotient of these polynomials is represented by a series of the form $d_0+d_1 z+d_2 z^2+\cdots$? I can't find a reason to it...

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question (which is why can the function be represented as a power series with no negative exponents) lies in considering the fact that it is analytic at $z=0$.

If the function is analytic at $z=0$, then by definition it has a Taylor Series expansion at that point.

To see that it is analytic at $z=0$ simply evaluate the expanded rational function, and notice that the denominator is reduced to $b_m$ which is non-zero. The numerator is just a polynomial, so no problems plugging in zero there.

Therefore the whole thing is analytic and has a Maclaurin expansion.

Answer (score 0):

What I'd do: We have $|P(z)/Q(z)|$ on the order of $1/|z|^2$ as $|z| \to \infty.$ By Cauchy, $$\int_C \frac{P(z)}{Q(z)}\,dz = \int_{|z|=R} \frac{P(z)}{Q(z)}\,dz$$ for large $R.$ Use the "M-L" estimate on the latter to see its absolute value is no more than a constant times $(1/R^2)\cdot2\pi R.$ The latter $\to 0$ as $R\to \infty.$ Conclusion: $\int_C \frac{P(z)}{Q(z)}\,dz = 0.$